# Throw exception without any real errors?

Tags: c#, exception

Can I use try-catch-throw for conditions that I set up, instead of actual errors? For example,

```
int x = 0;
if (x > 0)
{ throw new Exception("X can't be more than 0!");}
```

So there is nothing *technically wrong* with x being more than 0 but it is the condition that I have. Also, I know throw terminates the program but I need the program to keep running afterwards.

EDIT: Here is part of my code that I'm trying to implement this on:

```
public bool CheckIfEligible()
{

    
        if (DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now, this.startTime) > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n" + "ERROR: choose a later date");

            return false;


        }
    // bunch of other conditions here...
    else
        return true;

}
```

Comment: yes of course. the calling code can catch it just as well as it would catch any other exception. this is the standard use case for exceptions like the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, for example.

Comment: thanks! and how do i keep the code running?

Comment: wrap in try...catch

Comment: so... like:

try {
int x = 0;
if (x > 0)
{ throw new Exception("X can't be more than 0!");}
} catch {Console.WriteLine(""); } 
?
That doesn't look right haha but it might be!

Comment: yes; just try it! there is no point discussing this here in the comments of a Q/A stack :)

Comment: First of all, yes, you absolutely can. And while the CPU won't melt with x being greater than 0, you have a *contractual breakage* in that you don't expect nor allow x to be greater than 0. In this case, it's absolutely correct to throw an exception. I would, however, for this particular type of contract breaking advise you to use `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: @CeeMcSharpface yeah sorry i dont know why i was asking that instead of just trying myself. so i just tried it and 1- it doesnt throw the exception 2- it is in a bool method so the return statement is unreachable which is problematic. tried to put return in finally{} but that also gives an error.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen thanks I'll use that! But I'm not quite sure on how to implement the whole thing without terminating the entire code.

Comment: to salvage this, post a minimal complete example of the code you're actually running.

Comment: @CeeMcSharpface yes sir, just updated my original post.

Comment: Given your edit, it's also entirely OK to return true/false. There is no right or wrong answer here but rather "50 shades of gray". If you're writing a method akin to "check if the user typed in something OK", then I would consider a true/false approach better, because it is designed to accept input that may not be OK but that is part of its job, to determine that. If you need to know what is wrong with the input, a true/false + something else is also OK, for those details.

Comment: However, if the method is designed to do something with the input, and then is given incorrect input, according to whatever, then an exception might be more warranted because the method is designed to be expected to do its job, just now it can't. Again, there is no right or wrong approach here, ***it all depends***.

Comment: For instance, `File.Exists` returns true/false, depending on whether the file exists. However, `File.Open` throws an exception if the file doesn't exist, on the premise that you expect the file to be there since you asked the method to open it. So neither is wrong, or right, but it depends on the situation.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yeah I think my current approach would suffice normally but my lecturer wanted me to do exception handling and I've been at it for the whole day so I thought I'd use this platform as a last resort haha. So now I know that I need to throw an exception but it kind of messes with my current system in that it makes return false; unreachable and also terminates the program when in fact I need it to keep going.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen so I got it all to work by using a custom exception class, except for one thing: return false; is still unreachable. how may I fix that?

Comment: You don't. If you throw an exception, then code flow bubbles up to a matching try/catch block where the exception matches. Any code after a `throw` is unreachable by definition. My advise would be to consider a return statement as something benign, expected, sort of like asking your friend to tell you if the A-Team is showing on a channel. His response would be yes or no. But if you asked him if the A-Team was showing on a channel, and he knows that you knows that he doesn't even have a television, he would just look at you weirdly (aka throwing an exception). The question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you've hit one of the limitations of the Q&A format of Stack Overflow *main site*. The comments can only help so much. My advise to you would be to visit the chat forums instead. Since you've tagged this C# and your question seems to be mostly about code flow, I would advise you to visit the C# chatroom here. You can find it either by clicking the small icon all the way to the right, in the top bar here on the site, and then clicking Chat, and looking for C#, or clicking [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c) to go directly to it.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen thanks, this has been extremely informative. but i actually managed to return false by just putting it in catch!!! Thanks for everything! i will also check the chat forums to be informed about other code related things as well.

Comment: If you're having the try/catch in your method, and inside the try-block you do an if-statement and then optionally throw an exception, and then catch that exception in the surrounding try/catch block I first mentioned, and then return false in response ... I am going out on a limb here but I think it's safe to say your lecturer is not going to be impressed.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen English is not my mother tongue so I'm not 100% sure if I did what you claim, but I'll let you know of my grade under this comment section haha. i sure hope he won't be unimpressed, at least.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen -- hey, just wanted to say, my lecturer hasn't graded yet but said it was good. :)

Comment: @DenizDemir Glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually is generally a good practice to create custom exceptions that represents exceptional cases for your domain.

```
public class StartCannotBeInThePastException : Exception
{
    public StartCannotBeInThePastException(string message) : base(message)
    { }
}
```

That way to can handle specifically those exceptions that represents specific domain related errors, then log details or returning back to clients instead of making application crash for example. Also another benefit of doing custom exceptions is that you make your bussines rules explicit in the code, making it easier to read.

In this example would be something like this:

```
public void CheckIfEligible()
{
    if (DateTime.Now > this.startTime)
    {
        throw new StartCannotBeInThePastException();
    }
}
```

Exceptions have some hidden performance cost, if you are interested in that I leave you this video which explains it nice.

https://youtu.be/2f2elFRmeLE

Comment: This is too verbose and only useful if you are absolutely going to catch errors of that specific custom type, so I'd say only do it if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes you are not providing this code as a library somewhere, but are mainly concerned about doing these type of checks while you are developing it.

C# has the `[ConditionalAttribute("DEBUG")]` attribute which one can be add to a method which will do those checks, only when the code is in `DEBUG` mode and not release.

###### Why?

It allows to do sanity checks before we release.

What it means is, that the **call and the method** used, should only be *compiled* if this is a debug mode build. When the code is being built in `Release` mode, it won't ever be called or compiled into the exe; hence not doing development checks in release code that most likely won't see a *development* type failure.

For example

```
[ConditionalAttribute("DEBUG")]
private void CheckIfEligible(DateTime start, Datetime end)
{
    if (DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now, startTime) > 0)
        Console.WriteLine($"{Environment.Newline}ERROR: choose a later date");

    if (start > end)
      Console.WriteLine($"{Environment.Newline}ERROR: choose a earlier date");

}
```

Then in your code do something like this.

```
public void MyOperation()
{
   ....
   CheckIfEligible(myStartTime, myEndTime);

   // Normal processing no extra checks needed
   If () ...

}
```

This allows you to do the sanity checks which this process seems to suggest you want without compromising the end result.

Comment: hey, thanks! I actually just passed through the first problem by using a custom exception class. But since the "CheckIfEligible" is a bool, I need to return false but it is unreachable. how do I fix that? thank you

Edit: actually fixed it by just putting the return statement in catch! thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: Now you are asking us to design your program; to which SO is not the platform to do that. We can offer suggestions (which this is) and its up to the programmer to use or not. If this post is helpful mark it up. If it also is the *answer*, then mark it as such. Regardless, you need to only ask one question per post on an issue that is problem and not a design failure. :-)

Comment: my apologies if I stepped outside of the website's aim. I did end up managing to do it by myself thanks to you and others' help without anybody designing my program really though, so, thanks :)

Comment: We all have to learn, the difference between you and I was that there was no Internet (there was but not in this form) which one could seek help. Keep on asking. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should design your code such that the unintended state is never reached.

If it is reached, you missed something, and throwing an exception is adequate.

In these cases you would also want to fix the code if you notice one of these exceptions being thrown. The only case when this is not possible is when the exception are thrown for conditions you can't control.

Personally, I like to use `Trace.Assert()` for all errors that are not supposed to happen (unlike `Debug.Assert()`, these are kept in non-debug-build code). I also appreciate the time saved by not writing error messages for these errors that only I am supposed to debug (and that can only be solved by modifying the code).

For errors caused by external factors, I find throwing exceptions remains adequate.